# Создаёт ли fopen() при запуске папку?

Tags: c

В коде на C использую функцию `fopen("C:\\data\\data.txt", "w")`. Если на диске C папки data нет, то она не появляется, при этом не вылезает никаких ошибок и работа программы завершается корректно; если же создать пустую папку (без файлов) то в ней появится файл data.txt. Это нормальное поведение? Если он не создаёт папку, то куда пишется файл?

Comment: Нет. Для создания оглавлений служит `mkdir` (см. man) / В вашем случае нигде никакие файлы не создаются, просто Вы что-то неправильно проверяете в своей программе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В стандарте C не определено понятие директориев. Что касается имен файлов, то согласно стандарту (7.21.3 Files):

> 8 Functions that open additional (nontemporary) files require a file
>   name, which is a string. **The rules for composing valid file names
>   are implementation-defined**.

Обычно на уровне OS создание файлов и создание директориев или, по-другому, папок выполняется разными системными функциями, причем каждая операция имеет свои коды возвратов.

Поэтому это очень сомнительно, чтобы открытие файла включало в себя также создание промежуточных директориев.

Если вы действительно проверяете после вызова функции `fopen`, является ли указатель равным `NULL`, и он таковым не является, то это либо неопределенное поведение, либо implementation-defined поведение, описание которого надо искать в документации к той платформе, где программа запускается.

Вполне возможно, что просто идет запись в буфер, который по закрытии файла и завершении работы программы просто удаляется, так как его некуда записывать.